# how to use FluentUI Callout when target is MouseEvent?

Tags: reactjs, mouseevent, fluent-ui

I'm using [FluentUI Callout](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/callout) control in my project. The description of target property is this:

> The target that the Callout should try to position itself based on. It
> can be an element, a query selector string of a valid element, or a
> MouseEvent. If a MouseEvent is given, the origin point of the event
> will be used.

I want to set target as `MouseEvent` because I want Callout to appear at the position of the event (f.i. where user clicked). I also do not understand what is `origin point` in here.

Would it be possible to get some example of using Callout with MouseEvent as target ?

Thanks a lot!